# Should I use WCF or ASP.NET to write webservice?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I want to write webservice on .NET (my Client can be Android, iOS, Mac OS, Website...). My question is that I should use WCF or ASP.NET to do this?

Comment: WCF is a technology for web services. ASP.NET is used to build web pages. Would you like to clarify your question?

Comment: does This mean I should use WCF to build webservice?

Comment: With the introduction of ASP.net Web Apis you can use these in WCF, Windows services, Webforms, MVC, or whatever you want. I think depending on what you want to do WCF may be better, for other things Web APIs may be better as it's simpler to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean ASP.net Web Apis when you mention ASP.net. There is also ASP.net soap services but those won't be ideal to work with on platforms such as android or iOS.

If you are unsure about what the different web services are, you will most likely want to use ASP.net Web APIs as these are easy to set up and offer multiple content types, XML, JSON, possibly more...

WCF is more built for web services however it has a steep learning curve, which is why I say if you're unsure about what you want, you most likely aren't making something which will require WCF.

For more information I suggest reading: http://idesign.net/articles/asp_net_web_api_vs_wcf.htm

Comment: Thanks David. I am an java dev and I am messing with .net infrastructure. I can not clarify about Asp.net and WCF. I will do more researching base on your keyword. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a full story about ASP.NET Web API: http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Web%20API%20is%20now%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API It's just an integrated version of ASP.NET and WCF. Of course I will use ASP.NET Web APIs for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are asking for WCF or websevice. I think WCF is better option. For your refrence:

http://www.devdescent.com/2012/10/difference-between-wcf-and-web-service.html